# Python array syntax

Tags: php, python, arrays

Maybe is a stupid/easy question, but how should I interpet this type of array notation in python.

```
self.sessions[(recepientId, deviceId)]
```

I'm trying to translate some Python to PHP.

As someone said is unclear, is more unclear to me, so I'll put the full function. But I cannot do more, I don't know very well python.

```
   def loadSession(self, recepientId, deviceId):
    if self.containsSession(recepientId, deviceId):
        return SessionRecord(serialized=self.sessions[(recepientId, deviceId)])
    else:
        return SessionRecord()
```

The definition of the sessions variable is like this.

```
self.sessions = {}
```

Comment: I suggest you start to read about [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple), then go on to read about [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). Or better yet, start with a [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(recepientId, deviceId)` is a tuple consisting of two objects.
`self.sessions` is a dictionary (i.e. a key-value hash map).

The tuple is the *key* for which the associated value is retrieved from the dictionary by doing `self.sessions[(recepientId, deviceId)]`.
So it is simply a lookup for a specific value in a hash map (which is called a dictionary in Python).

Comment: Thank you, just my last question, as PHP doesn't have tuples, and it don't let you use another array as key, the solution could be creating a string key of both values concatenated in the same order.

Comment: @Payn3: FWIW, concatenation is how the awk language handles indices for multidimensional arrays. But it's a Good Idea to keep some kind of separator between the items, don't just run them together without a separator. So try to use a separator that will never occur in either `recepientId` or `deviceId`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought about putting a separator just because i have to get in the future the values separated.

Answer (score 1):

This code is just trying to find the SessionRecord among others in self.sessions (it's key-value map) by key, where key is a pair of recipientId and deviceId.

In C++, Java, C# etc. one would rather write something like:

```
class Key {
//constructor
Id recipientId;
Id deviceId;
//getters|setters and stuff
}
Map<Key, SessionRecord> sessions = Store.getSessions();
SessionRecord session = sessions.get(new Key(recipientId, deviceId));
```